# Na/NaN/Inf Error when trying to perform a MANOVA on 128 Variable dataframe from .csv

Tags: r, csv, na, summary, manova

At the minute I'm importing a csv as a dataframe that I was hoping to perform a MANOVA on. The dataframe is 128 numeric variables classed into 'Site' of 3 levels.

In R all of the variable '`featx`' columns are either numeric or integer.

```
audiosets <- read.csv("AM_SUBSET_E_D_and_VJR.csv", header = TRUE) 

audiosets.manova1 <- manova (cbind(feat1, feat2, feat3, feat4, feat5, feat6, feat7, feat8, feat9, feat10, feat11, feat12, feat13, feat14, feat15,
                                   feat16, feat17, feat18, feat19, feat20, feat21, feat22, feat23, feat24, feat25, feat26, feat27, feat28, feat29,
                                   feat30,feat31, feat32, feat33, feat34, feat35, feat36, feat37, feat38, feat39, feat40, feat41, feat42, feat43,
                                   feat44, feat45, feat46, feat47, feat48, feat49, feat50, feat51, feat52, feat53, feat54, feat55, feat56, feat57,
                                   feat58, feat59, feat60, feat61, feat62, feat63, feat64, feat65, feat66, feat67, feat68, feat69, feat70, feat71,
                                   feat72, feat73, feat74, feat75, feat76, feat77, feat78, feat79, feat80, feat81, feat82, feat83, feat84, feat85,
                                   feat86, feat87, feat88, feat89, feat90, feat91, feat92, feat93, feat94, feat95, feat96, feat97, feat98, feat99,
                                   feat100, feat101, feat102, feat103, feat104, feat105, feat106, feat107, feat108, feat109, feat110, feat111,
                                   feat112, feat113, feat114, feat115, feat116, feat117, feat118, feat119, feat120, feat121, feat122, feat123,
                                   feat124, feat125, feat126, feat127, feat128) ~ as.factor(Site), data = audiosets)
```

is the code I'm currently using however when I try to run:

```
summary(audiosets.manova1)
```

It throws up the following error:

```
    Error in qr.default(D %*% ss[[nt]] %*% D, tol = tol) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

I've checked the class of all the feat columns and they're all either numeric or integer so I wondered what's causing this issue?

I was trying to convert the whole dataframe to numeric but I was having trouble with that as well.

Note also: in the columns where its given the class 'integer' all of the values in those columns are 0.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: ALSO: Sorry, running the MANOVA doesn't throw up any error and I get an output of different types of data, it's just when I try to run the summary command - Thanks!

Comment: You can edit your post and add clarifying comments to the post Becky... Happy Bug squashing.

Comment: Because the dataset is not available for us to demonstrate with, there's not much specific I can think of to suggest.  Is there a smaller example that can be included in your question?  If not, I'd start small, with maybe one or two column that you know aren't [rank deficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/what-is-rank-deficiency-and-how-to-deal-with-it).  Then add a few columns at  time until you find the problem.  Not that it may be a combination of columns, not a single column.